# Display values of HTMLTableCellElement

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access a value from an html `<tr>` element when it is clicked as follows:

```
<body>
       <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <% viewObj.forEach(function(obj) { %>
                <tr onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <th scope="row"><%= x %></th>
                <td><%= JSON.stringify(obj.completion_date).slice(1,11) %></td>
                <td> <%= obj.wo_num %></td>
                <td><%= obj.drawing_num %></td>
                <td><%= obj.m_programming %></td>
                <td><%= obj.m_machining %></td>
                <td><%= obj.m_programming + obj.m_machining %></td>
            <% x++;}); %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
<script>
        function myFunction(x) {
            alert("name: " + x.cells[0]);
        }
</script>
```

When I click on a row in the table, I get the following alert box:
[image]

How do I access the values of the `HTMLTableCellElement`?

Comment: `x.cells[0].textContent`

Comment: That works thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Barmar, to access the values of the `HTMLTableCellElement` in my case would be:

```
<script>
   function myFunction(x) {
      console.log(x.cells[1].textContent);
   }
</script>
```